# Ajax, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

I ran into an issue for which I cannot find the answer, I rarely ask questions here, but I am rather stumped. Any assistance shall be appreciated.

This is the **PHP** that receives the **Ajax** call.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["my_data"] = $_POST['action'];

    $DB_HOSTNAME = 'localhost';
    $DB_USERNAME = 'username';
    $DB_PASSWORD = 'password';

    $link2 = mysqli_connect($DB_HOSTNAME,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD) or die('Unable to establish a DB1 connection');
    mysqli_select_db($link2, '$DB_USERNAME');

    $orderQuery = mysqli_query($link2, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$_SESSION['my_data']."'");
    $orderQuery = mysqli_fetch_assoc($orderQuery);

    $orderInfo = "
        <table class='table table-striped'>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>#: </td>
                <td>". $_SESSION['my_data'] ."</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Full name: </td>
                <td>". $orderQuery['firstname'] . " " . $orderQuery['lastname'] ."</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Address: </td>
                <td> ". $orderQuery['shipping_address_1'] ."<br> ". $orderQuery['shipping_city'] . " " . $orderQuery['shipping_zone'] . " " . $orderQuery['shipping_postcode'] ." </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Card Expiry Date Month: </td>
                <td> 08 </td>
            </tr>        
        </tbody>
    </table><br>
    ";

    echo $orderInfo/* . $_POST['action']*/;   ?>
```

And this is the script that makes the call.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var myWindow;
    function myFunction() {
    myWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
    myWindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'>");

    var orderNum;
    orderNum = document.getElementsByClassName('summary_value')[0].innerHTML;
    orderNum = orderNum.replace("#", "");

    $.ajax( { type : 'POST',
      data : {'action':orderNum},
      url  : 'process.php',
      success: function ( data ) {
        myWindow.document.write( data );
      },
      error: function ( xhr ) {
        alert( "error" );
      }
    });

    myWindow.document.write("<br>");
    myWindow.document.write(document.getElementById("payInfor").innerHTML);
    }

</script>
<button onclick='myFunction()' class="btn btn-default">Print Pay Info</button>
```

It could be a simple issue, but I can't see it.

I know the Ajax is working because it displays some of the information `($_SESSION['my_data'])`, so I am thinking it's something with my SQL statements, but the syntax looks correct.

Comment: What errors do you face?

Comment: `mysqli_select_db($link2, '$DB_USERNAME');` when you have singlequtotes, it'll not be a variable, but that exact string instead. Then, enable error-reporting for PHP and check the console for any JS errors, get MySQLi to tell you about any errors there using `mysqli_error()` (or set MySQLi to throw exceptions). Debugging by getting the errors the script throws back at you is always the first stop! Then you should use **parameterized queries**, you already have an API that supports it.

Comment: Sql injection vulnerablities on a site that takes credit card payments? Wow

Comment: @andrew I add cleanup and security once the code is functional. Also this page is protected by an admin password and the people who do have access aren't tech savvy enough to know what sql injection is. Thank you for taking note of that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_select_db()` expects parameter one to be the connection and parameter two to be the database name. In your case you are passing `'$DB_USERNAME'`. So your code will look to connect to database named `'$DB_USERNAME'` because of the single quotes. Change it to the database name instead. Either `$DB_NAME` or `'database_name'` should work. While in development mode, try enabling `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to catch errors like this.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance i think that `mysqli_select_db($link2, '$DB_USERNAME');` here is the error.

it must be `mysqli_select_db($link2, $DB_USERNAME);` or `mysqli_select_db($link2, $DB_NAME);`

Comment: variable inside quotes will act as a variable, so that not seems to be an error

Comment: That's for double quotes, this one are single quotes

Answer (score 1):

try to replace this `mysqli_fetch_assoc` with `mysqli_fetch_array`

and `($link2, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$_SESSION['my_data']."'")`

with `($link2, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=".$_SESSION['my_data']."")`

note: remove single quote (' ') for id